# Have frontend javascript access text file that is private to users

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm having trouble putting into words what I want, but I'll try to explain better. What I want to do is have the javascript (or another solution, if there is one) be able to access a text file on a static site and use data from the text file (in whatever way). The catch is I don't want users browsing to the website to be able to access the text file itself, but only be able to see the output of however I use the file and display results. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, javascript is running on the user's machine. Whatever file it can request from your server could also be requested by your user as well.

Comment: There is nothing that client side code can access that you can keep private from users.

Comment: It is impossible to prevent users to access what your script can access. However you can make it in JSON form and does not include more than what you process and show your users. You obviously don't place any direct link to that file anywhere on your pages then users will not care to read it directly.

Comment: Like others said, a skilled user will always be able to manually replicate whatever your JavaScript does. You can obfuscate things by hiding data behind JSON and using php or another server side scripting language to access your actual file, so end users can't see the entire file but you can't hide any potential "answers" to JSON requests your front end might execute.

Answer (score 1):

Like AVAVT et al. said, you can't do this. But you could transfer/obfuscate text data in your Javascript code text (though you can't prevent a user from viewing your script, so this isn't going to stop aggressive attempts at getting your raw data, if that's what you want).